# Trying to create a static framework library and getting lipo error (can't open input file)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, shell, frameworks

Trying to build my SDK framework via terminal and I am getting the following error.

```
lipo: for current configuration (Release) creating output file: build/dist/libMySDK.a
find: build/Release-iphoneos/include: No such file or directory
```

I am thinking this has to do with where my DerivedData file is?

This is the line its barfing on

```
#copy headers
find build/${cfg}-iphoneos/include -name '*.h' -exec cp {} build/dist/Headers \;
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what this error means, but when i build a static library i find the .a more problematic then .framework.

And i use this short tutorial:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/stevez/archive/2013/02/04/create-your-own-ios-framework.aspx

It worked great, no errors, maybe it will help you with this essue

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. I needed to go through xCode and set it to export the header files (i.e. .h files) that I wanted users of the SDK to see.

```
Settings > Build Phases > Copy Files (i.e. not 'Copy Bundle Resources' as that is for a non-SDK project)
```